# Select rows that doesn't appear in inner join pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes, A and B, and I want to create from them two other dataframes.

A_out will include all the rows that appear in A but doesn't appear in the inner join between A and B (based on the first two columns)

Similarly, B_out will include all the rows that appear in B but doesn't appear in the inner join between A and B.

For example - for the dataframes:

A:

```
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

B:

```
b  2
c  3
d  4
```

The expected output would be:

A_out:

```
a  1
```

B_out:

```
d  4
```

I tried to  achieve this task with the following code:

```
common = pileup_df.merge(lists_df.drop_duplicates(), on=['identifier', 'position'], how='left', indicator=True)
out_pileup = common[common['_merge'] == 'left_only']
common = lists_df.merge(pileup_df.drop_duplicates(), on=['identifier', 'position'], how='left', indicator=True)
out_lists = common[common['_merge'] == 'left_only']
out_pileup.to_csv('nand_pileup', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
out_lists.to_csv('nand_lists', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
```

But the results seem a bit weird to me so I would love some feedback about this since my logic might be wrong here but I just don't realize that.

EDIT:

I ran `wc -l` on the input and output dataframes

```
A - 2576459
B - 23194
A_out - 2563980
B_out - 10715
```

And the fact that `A_out + B_out = A` makes me suspicious

Comment: I think logic is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your solution or simplify it by one outer join if need unique not matched values:

```
common = (pileup_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['identifier', 'position'])
                   .merge(lists_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['identifier', 'position']),
                           on=['identifier', 'position'], 
                           how='outer', 
                           indicator=True))
print (common)
  identifier  position      _merge
0          a         1   left_only
1          b         2        both
2          c         3        both
3          d         4  right_only


out_pileup = common[common['_merge'] == 'left_only']
out_lists = common[common['_merge'] == 'right_only']

print (out_pileup)
  identifier  position     _merge
0          a         1  left_only

print (out_lists)
  identifier  position      _merge
3          d         4  right_only
```

Comment: Getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'merge'` from this expression `common = (pileup_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['identifier', 'position']`.
Also, small syntax error - you are missing two brackets after specifying `indicator=True`

Comment: @EliranTurgeman - Thank you, edited. Still same problem? If yes, it means `pileup_df` or `lists_df` is list, not DataFrame.

Comment: Working now. Could you please look at the edit I made? something about the numbers there seems suspicious to me

Comment: @EliranTurgeman - Is possible remove duplicaated and then test? Also I try sum it and get `A_out + B_out = 2574695`

Comment: I  tried to merge without drop_duplicates like that: `common = (pileup_df.merge(lists_df, on=['identifier', 'position'], how='outer',indicator=True))`
Still got same results